# WCF Service Problem with not supported mimetype

Tags: c#, wcf, basichttpbinding

I am constructing a simple WCF service. My web.config is the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <system.serviceModel>
<bindings>
    <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="MyBasicHttpBinding">
            <security mode="None">
                <transport clientCredentialType="None" />
            </security>
        </binding>
    </basicHttpBinding>
</bindings>
<services>
  <!-- This section is optional with the default configuration
    model introduced in .NET Framework 4 -->
  <service name="WcfService1.Service1" behaviorConfiguration="MyServiceTypeBehaviors">

    <endpoint address="http://companyserver/wcftest/service1.svc"
              binding="basicHttpBinding"
      bindingConfiguration="MyBasicHttpBinding"
              contract="WcfService1.IService1" />

    <endpoint address="mex"
              binding="mexHttpBinding"
              contract="IMetadataExchange" />
  </service>
</services>
<behaviors>
    <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="MyServiceTypeBehaviors" >
            <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
        </behavior>
    </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>

  </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

When I am trying to consume the service it presents the following error message:

Content Type application/soap+xml; charset=utf-8 was not supported by service http://companyserver/wcftest/Service1.svc.  The client and service bindings may be mismatched.

Comment: How do you consume the service? The exceptions says that your client sends request in SOAP 1.2 but your service expects SOAP 1.1

Answer (score 0):

Check the binding configurations in your client and service. There must be a discrepancy there. For instance, are you using the same security model on both client and server?